# Is a defined app_name recommended in urls.py for Django 2?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-2.2

I'm trying to figure out what the best practices are around writing `urls.py` files in my Django app. I'm updating an old project to Django 2, and I read in the update documentation that `urls.py` files should be properly namespaced. A bit of googling suggests to me to define `app_name` in my `urls.py` always, so you don't have to manually add the app_name to each url endpoint. Instead you can then access it like ("`app_name`:`url_name`").

In my project I have:

```
avatar/urls.py
services/urls.py
```

So in this case, I am not sure how to name them, but for now I've gone with `app_name = "avatar"` in `avatar/urls.py` and `app_name = "avatar-services"` in `services/urls.py`.

Do these both need an `app_name` for proper namespacing? Is it best practice to always have a defined `app_name` per `urls.py`? I'm uncertain still if this is required or even recommended. If I've understood correctly, it's just for easier/logical access of the url, not strictly required, but recommended in the sense that it's easier to follow.

EDIT: Updated to make example more clear.

Comment: is `tests` an actual app or just unit/integration tests for `avatar`?

Comment: In this case it is just unit/integration tests. However, I have some other Django apps where I do have multiple apps underneath it. Sorry, I should have picked a better example. I updated it to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have gathered, the answer more generally is:

1. Where possible to logically break down your app into smaller apps, they should have their own `urls.py` for their views.
2. Each app should have an `app_name` defined in that `urls.py`.
3. Sometimes the breakdown may not make sense or may not provide its own views, such as a `tests` app.

In the case for my question, yes each of `avatar` and `services` should have their own `urls.py` with an `app_name`, say `app_name = "avatar"` and `app_name = "services"` respectively. They are then accessed via `("avatar:<url_name>")` and `("services:<url_name>")`. However, in some cases you might not do this. For example, there is also a `tests` directory in my main app, but it is just unit and integration tests and does not provide its own `views.py` or `urls.py`. It's not necessary to force it in such a case.

This is my current understanding so feel free to correct me if I was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

For me the best way is to convert the urlpatterns into a tuple, passing the appname as a second element

```
urlpatterns = ([
    path(..., name='some name'),
    path(...., name='some name'),
    .....
], 'appname')
```

Comment: Thanks for the input here, I did not know it could be done that way.

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple `urls.py` files in not mandatory, but recommended for each app. If it's possible to logically separate your main app into smaller apps, then you should do it. Each app will have it's own model, urls.py, views etc. Tests can be part of each app.